# Prevent Screenshot in gnome using xmodmap

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, xmodmap, print-screen

I want to prevent screenshots from being taken in GNOME using keyboard shortcuts.
I need to do this by running a script in such a manner that it can be reverted later.

I tried to do this using `xmodmap` by remapping the <kbd>PrintScr</kbd>/<kbd>SysRq</kbd> key to `NoSymbol`.

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Print='
```

This did not work.
I had faced a similar problem while disabling task switching using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key -- then I had just remapped the keycode to `NoSymbol`.
However this same approach does not seem to be working right now.

What is going wrong here?
And what can I do to make it right?

Also is there any other methods I should be looking into?

Comment: Probably useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3737